# Google Docs - Highlighting list text

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm going to be taking a ton of notes, and I study best if I can just write quickly without thinking about formatting. So, I want to be able to run a script that will highlight different parts of my ListItems so they're easier to go back over and read. I'm new with javascript, and just as new with Google apps scripts. Here's what I've got so far, and based on my understanding of the documentation, this should work...

```
function highlightNotes() {

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var listItems = body.getListItems();

  for (var item in listItems){
    var item = body.getChild(item);
    if (item.Attribute.NESTING_LEVEL == 0){
      item.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#FFFF00";
    }
  }
}
```

Also, my main experience is python, so it may be I'm just doing something wrong with assumed  syntax.  The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "NESTING_LEVEL" from undefined.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `getNestingLevel'? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#getNestingLevel()

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Quite simply because I didn't know it existed. I was playing with it though just before you responded, and now I'm trying to figure out how to change the background color, as I think the getNestingLevel fixed it. Would it be listItems[item].Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#FFFF00"; ???

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was hopelessly stuck, but I figured it out.

```
for (var item in listItems){
  var item = body.getChild(item);
  if (item.getNestingLevel() == 0){
    item.asText().setBackgroundColor(#FFFF00");
  }
}
```

Carry on... nothing to see here...